# Angular: test case fail .focus is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a method which looks something like:

```
checkMyInput($event) {
    const a = $event.target;
    if (bla bla bla) {
        a.focus();
}
```

My test case for this method looks something like:

```
it("test checkMyInput", ()=>{
   let $event = {
                   target: {
                         value: 'abc'
                        }
                }
   component.checkMyInput($event);
```

However, when I run it I keep get error that a.focus is not a function

I saw some answers that you need to spy on the element, I tried but didn't work.
I just need to test this method in the component level. It's trigger by one of the event listener.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
let $event =  {
        target {
          focus: jasmine.createSpy('focus')
               }
       }
```